# Pandas replace values in a mixed datatype column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, that has a column 'A1' that contains strings, postive as well as negative integers. I want to replace the all integers >= 0 with True and everyting else with false (strings, neg. int, etc.)

My DataFrame looks like this:

| index | A1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | Hello |
| 2 | -8 |
| 3 | Hello |

and shall look like this:

| index | A1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | True |
| 1 | False |
| 2 | False |
| 3 | False |

I tried it this way, but then I drop all other columns:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(pd.to_numeric(df['A1'], errors="coerce").agg(lambda x: x.ge(0)))
```

How can I do this so the rest of the DataFrame is kept?

Comment: try something - df1["A2"]=df1["A1"].str.isnumeric()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.assign(A1 = pd.to_numeric(df['A1'], errors="coerce").ge(0))
```

Or:

```
df['A1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A1'], errors="coerce").ge(0)
```